# Use a library function in the apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, word-count

I have a dataframe with a column named 'msgText' that contains texts. For this, I want to create another column named 'wordcount' that counts how many words each row of 'msgText' contains.

The column looks as follows:

```
head(all_transcripts$msgText)
[1]  "Hi, my name is Chris and I am a programmer"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[2]  "I have worked with R for 12 years"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[3]  "Being a programmer I have many questions" 
[4]  "The fellow programmers at Stackoverflow help me to get the answer"                                                                                                                                                                                  
[5]  "This help has saved my life many times."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[6]  "Thanks Stackoverflow!"
```

And the result that I would like is:

```
head(all_transcripts$wordcount)
    [1]  10                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    [2]  8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    [3]  7 
    [4]  11                                                                                                                                                                                  
    [5]  8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    [6]  2
```

To do so, I use the `ngram` library with the `wordcount` function.

I've tried:

```
all_transcripts$wordcount <- apply(all_transcripts, 2, 
                                   wordcount(all_transcripts$msgText))
```

However, doing this I got the following error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) :    'wordcount(all_transcripts$msgText)' is
not a function, character or symbol
```

How could I use the `apply` function properly without having to use a for loop on my dataset?

Comment: I think you are looping through the column and then extracting the column again.  Perhaps you need just `all_transcripts$wordcount <- wordcount(all_transcripts$msgText)`

Comment: No that does not work, then it gets the wordcount for all the words in the entire column

Comment: Could you post a small sample of your data? Then we would be easier able to help.

Comment: Emil, you're going to need to provide a more reproducible example. Please provide sample data in an *unambiguous* format, such as `dput(head(all_transcripts))`, as well as your intended/expected output (as it is not clear exactly what you mean based on your description).

Comment: You need a function in that third argument to `apply`. Right now instead of a function, you've got whatever is returned by `wordcount(all_transcripts$msgText)`... probably a vector

Comment: Maybe `all_transcripts$wordcount <- sapply(all_transcripts$msgText, wordcount)` ?

Comment: I have changed my question, is it more clear what I want now?

Comment: @akrun In each row, it returned the total number of words of the entire column. So it did not apply the function on a per row basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the elements of the 'msgText' and apply the `wordcount` function

```
library(ngram)
library(tidyverse)
all_transcripts %>%
     mutate(wordcount = map_int(msgText, wordcount))
#                                                             msgText wordcount
#1                        Hi, my name is Chris and I am a programmer        10
#2                                 I have worked with R for 12 years         8
#3                          Being a programmer I have many questions         7
#4 The fellow programmers at Stackoverflow help me to get the answer        11
#5                           This help has saved my life many times.         8
#6                                             Thanks Stackoverflow!         2
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
all_transcripts$wordcount <- sapply(all_transcripts$msgText, wordcount)
```

---

The issue in the OP's code is it is looping through the column (`MARGIN = 2` in `apply`), where the vector (`alltranscripts$wordcount`) doesn't have the `dim` attribute

#### data

```
all_transcripts <- structure(list(msgText = c("Hi, my name is Chris and I am a programmer", 
"I have worked with R for 12 years", "Being a programmer I have many questions", 
"The fellow programmers at Stackoverflow help me to get the answer", 
"This help has saved my life many times.", "Thanks Stackoverflow!"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vectorized `lengths` with `strsplit` for word count using base R:

```
all_transcripts$word_count <- lengths(strsplit(all_transcripts$text, split=" "))

all_transcripts

#                                                                text word_count
# 1                        Hi, my name is Chris and I am a programmer         10
# 2                                 I have worked with R for 12 years          8
# 3                          Being a programmer I have many questions          7
# 4 The fellow programmers at Stackoverflow help me to get the answer         11
# 5                           This help has saved my life many times.          8
# 6                                             Thanks Stackoverflow!          2
```

**Data**

```
all_transcripts <- data.frame(text=c("Hi, my name is Chris and I am a programmer",
                                     "I have worked with R for 12 years",
                                     "Being a programmer I have many questions",
                                     "The fellow programmers at Stackoverflow help me to get the answer",
                                     "This help has saved my life many times.",
                                     "Thanks Stackoverflow!"),
                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```